# Is it possible to get a better quality by increase the frame rate, even if I don't have the raw footage?

Tags: framerate

Is it possible to improve the quality of a movie just be rediting the finished product to have more fps?  Or do you still need the original raw footage to actually increase the quality?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense as written.  I assume you meant to ask if it is possible to increase the quality by increasing the BIT rate, which is something completely different from frame rate.  The frame rate is how many frames are played per second and increasing it would just make your video play faster (like it was being fast forwarded.)

Comment: computer… zoom in… enhance

Answer (score 2):

If you are really talking about frame rate, then if you tried to invent new frames while maintaining the speed of playback, your quality level would go down (likely significantly).

If you didn't mind it looking like someone was watching a fast forwarded version of your video, increasing the frame rate should have some increase in quality as long as the frame rate isn't too high already due to the dithering impact over time resulting in better apparent quality (this is why still frames of video don't look as good as playing the video.)

If you actually meant bit rate (the amount of data being used to encode each frame), then no, all that would happen on the re-encode is that your existing problems would be preserved with less additional quality loss, but it is impossible to restore quality by increasing bitrate.  The information is already lost.  In fact, if you do highly lossy compression more than once, the quality loss starts growing exponentially as the random noise destroys the effectiveness of compression algorithms.

This is why renders are run from the highest available source so that the compression can make the best use of real information without having to waste bits on trying to compress noise.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still an amature at this, ans only have at my disposal home based applications.  So when I say FPS, thats exactly what I mean, not the bit rate.  Also I have increased the bit rate to 120000 kbps with 2 pass encoding, at 120 fps, and the video quality does not change, only difference is the file gets larger.

Comment: @ANonymous no need to apologize.  We all had to start at the beginning.  It just wasn't very clear what you were trying to ask since contextually it didn't make a lot of sense since changing the frame rate would drastically impact the way the footage plays so I can't think of many cases where it would be meaningfully useful.  Unfortunately, video is a CICO process (crap in, crap out).  If you start with something with quality issues, there isn't a whole lot you can do to increase the quality, certainly not without trade offs.